# Incorrect tabs while printing Excel cells to a textfile in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing, tabs

I'm a beginner in VBA and I'm trying to print the cells in figure 1 and want the output seen on figure 2. But instead I'm getting the output in figure 3.

## Excel cells I want to print(figure 1):

[image: Excel cells I want to print(figure 1)]

## Desired output(figure 2):

[image: Desired output(figure 2)]

## The actual output(figure 3):

[image: The actual output(figure 3)]

This is the code I used:

```
Open FileName For Output As fileNumber
 
Print #fileNumber, "IO" + Chr(9) + "Name" + Chr(9) + Chr(9)
+ "NO/NC/Pulse" +Chr(9) + "Type" + Chr(9) + "Function" + vbCrLf
 
For i = 9 To lastRow
 
Print #fileNumber, Cells(i, 1) & Chr(9) & Cells(i, 2) & Chr(9) & Cells(i, 8) 
& Chr(9) & Cells(i, 9) & Chr(9) & Cells(i, 3)
 
Next i
```

Comment: It appears all you need to do is add some more tabs in your code. It would be easier to determine exactly how many tabs you need programmatically if you used a fixed-width text.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thank you I changed the title. But I don't know how to use a fixed-width text.

Comment: I'm sure there's an easier way, which is why I didn't provide as an answer. But with fixed-width font (aka [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)) you can determine how many characters would fit inside a tab, because all the characters would be the same size. But I would just wait to see if someone else has a better suggestion.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thanks for your response! I will try it out.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thank you I got it working now, using your method.